# ¿Cómo contar las repeticiones de cada 2 elementos de un arreglo en Python?

Tags: python

alguien sabe como hacer un contador de repeticiones que se salte un numero?
por ejemplo tengo ['2', '7', '8', '4', '2', '5', '7', '6', '10', '1'] y quiero contar el numero de repeticiones de cada dos números, es decir que se salte el 7, 4 , 5, 6, 1. entonces del ejemplo anterior el contador me debería devolver que el 2 se repite 2 veces

aquí esta el código que hice con lo que me explicaron,
al ejecutarlo me da este contador que no es el que necesito {0: 1, 2: 1, 4: 1, 6: 1, 8: 1} cuando me tiene que dar {2:2, 8:1, 7:1, 10:1}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Claro. En lugar de `range(len(lista)):` usas `range(0, len(lista), 2)`, con lo que recorres la lista de dos en dos.

Comment: O trabaja sobre `lista[::2]` que es un _slice_ de tu lista que contiene ya solo los elementos que has dicho (debido al 2 final, que hace que se tome uno de cada 2)

Comment: Solo te haría falta saber que `list.count(element)` sirve para contar la cantidad de elementos en una lista. `lista[::2].count('2')` cuenta la cantidad de `'2'` en la lista saltando de 2 en 2.

Comment: por favor me podrían mostrar como escribirlo en un código de Python?

Comment: Si no sabes hacer un código con lo que te han dicho hasta ahora, entonces tal vez debas practicar algo más basico para poder entenderlo...

Comment: No tengo intención de ofender, perdón si ofendo.

Comment: ya se que me han ayudado, ya hice un código con lo que me dijeron pero no termina de funcinoar , es decir me funciona para este ejemplo pero quiero hacer un código que funcione para cualquier lista y todavía no logro hacerlo

Comment: Edita la pregunta para mostrar el código que has hecho, y así podemos indicarte qué está mal

Comment: En tu bucle `n` itera por los enteros 0, 1, 2, 3, 4... ya que eso es lo que devuelve `range()`, números consecutivos en vez de los números de la lista. Puedes cambiar `range(0., len(numeros), 2)` por `numeros[::2]` para que `n` vaya tomando directamente los valores de los números, en vez de los índices, o bien usar `lista[n]` dentro del bucle para acceder a cada número, cuando `n` es el índice (dejando en este caso el `range()` como lo tenías)

Comment: Muchas gracias, llevo un buen rato tratando de hacer esto

Comment: saben que tipo de modificación le puedo hacer al código para que me cuente solo los que se repiten mas de una vez?

Comment: ponle un `if lista.count(n)>1`